# How to fetch data from 2 table using where in mysql?

Tags: mysql, database

I'm making a database for a Medical center. In my case I need to fetch data using 2 tables. I have 2 tables named `Consultation` and `Channeling`. In my case when the patient place a new Channeling, it will be automatically adding to the Consultation table. Then, when the patient done their consultation, that consultation record will be removed. But the `Channeling` record is not removing(According to the business case). I need to fetch the records from `Channeling`  records, that **Not Existing** in the `Consultation` table. I tried with this,

```
SELECT c.* FROM Channeling c, Consultation cn WHERE c.cid!=cn.cid
```

`cid` is the primary key of `Channeling` table. It is a foreign key of `Consultation`. When i'm using this query, I got 700+ records. But in my `Channelin` table has only 75 records. How could I do this. Is it possible? I'm using mysql database.

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider your query as a cartesian product being filtered by the WHERE clause. So it is like getting 75 x `Consultation records count` records and then discard all those combinations where

```
c.cid=cn.cid
```

That is why you get more elements than `Channelin` has.

To get what you want, you can try with:

```
SELECT c.* FROM Channeling c WHERE 0 = (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM Consultation cn WHERE cn.cid=c.cid);
```

Or:

```
SELECT c.* FROM Channeling c WHERE c.id NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT cn.id FROM Consultation cn);
```

It is not the same:

*To select all combinations of Channeling and Consultation  elements with different id's*

Than:

*To select all elements from Channeling not being present at Consultation*

Answer (score 0):

You are select every possible combination of consultations and channelings and then filtering out the ones with the same ID.

Try something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM Channeling WHERE cid NOT IN (SELECT cid FROM Consultation)
```

Answer (score 0):

you are doing cartesian product of two tables and then select records which have condition `c.cid=cn.cid`. You can do this by left joining two table. This will return all records of channeling and then select records which have consultation's Id column null. Like this

```
SELECT  c.*
FROM Channeling c
LEFT JOIN Consultation cn
ON c.cid = cn.cid 
WHERE cn.cid IS NULL
```